# How to change EmitDefaultValue in automatically created Nuget

Tags: c#, swagger, nuget, swashbuckle

I'm using a C# application with microservices and using swagger/openAPI and swashbuckle to automatically generate nugets from my code. I have some int properties which are getting EmitDefaultValue=false in the generated nuget, which causes 0 value to not be serialized. I tried everything I could think of to change this but couldn't.

Example property:

```
[Range(-1, int.MaxValue)]
[DefaultValue(-1)]
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
public int Some Number { get; set; } = -1;
```

As you can see my default is -1, meaning 0 holds significance, so I don't want 0 ignored.

These are my swashbuckle packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="6.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="6.1.4" />
```

Found this on github about others with the same issue:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3274

issue seems to have been resolved but I couldn't understand how to implement it.
Any help would be appreciated, I don't want to add a schema filter to all properties since this is specific only for very few properties and the others should continue ignoring 0.

Comment: you say "generated nuget" - is it actually generating nupkg files? or is it generating C#? the reason I ask is: if it is generating C# we might still have options - for example some serializers will respect "conditional serialization" patterns, for example `partial class Whatever { public bool ShouldSerializeNumber() => Number != -1; }` - although that depends on the exact serializer being used

Comment: It is generating c#, though I'm not sure what serializers are being used. I'd rather not create a custom serializer just for 2 properties, is there no attribute or anything that can help here?

Comment: I wasn't proposing creating a custom serializer - just trying to work around the behaviour by adding a *single method* (per affected member) that might (depending on the serializer being used) make the problem go away; adding the method via a `partial class` avoids the problem of hand-editing the generated C#

Comment: for example, your csproj mentions Newtonsoft; Newtonsoft [supports this pattern](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm) (as does `XmlSerializer`, as does protobuf-net, and `DataContractSerializer` supports something *similar*)

Comment: I am using newtonsoft and the option you gave of using ShouldSerialize functions sounds like a possible solution to my issue. I'll try it out, Thanks (:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.